# When is diacetyl desirable?

Tags: beer-styles

I've heard there are beer styles that purposefully create diacetyl as part of the flavor profile. What styles (or even specific brews) intentionally create diacetyl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English Ales, Czech lagers, and Chardonnay wines; to name a few.